# XMLHttpRequest output not shown

Tags: javascript

Here is my JavaScript function:-

Solved JavaScript function:-

```
function delfile(fileid) {
  var div = "fileid_" + fileid;
  var location = "/delfile/" + fileid;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } 
  else
  {
    var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
    {
      document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", location, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("");
}
```

Here is what I generate from PHP:-

```
echo "<td><div id='fileid_{$id}'><button onclick='delfile({$id})'>Delete File</button></div></td>";
```

My problem is that when user clicks on 2-3 links simultaneously, the http requests are sent via javascript and the files are deleted on the server but the div id's are not updated with the output of the http-request. Only the button on which the user last clicked gets the output of the http-request.

There is absolutely no problem in the PHP script, I just gave it for reference. The delfile script just sends "File Delted".

Solved by using local variables as suggested by @torazaburo.

Comment: Please remove MS cruft. It applies only to IE6 and below. You can also remove all other XMLHttpRequest boilerplate while you're at it, we know how that works. Just out of curiosity, what 8-year-old book did you copy this from?

Comment: I want it to work on IE 6, so can't remove it.

Comment: IE6 share is under 1% in all developed countries. See https://www.modern.ie/en-us/ie6countdown. It will drop to zero soon when MS ceases XP support. Whether or not you want to keep it is up to you, but please don't clog up your code samples with such irrelevant details.

Comment: I will remove that, but can you answer my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've failed to declare `xmlhttp` local to the function, which means it's shared among multiple requests, which is a recipe for disaster.

While you're at it, please also declare `$div` and `$location` local to the function. Also, please remove the `$` prefix to those variable names, as this practice is known to rot the brain.

Your failure to declare the variables would have been picked up if you had put a "use strict;" at the top of your function, as you should.

Comment: How do I declare it as a local variable ?

Comment: In the way that is described in the first paragraph of JS tutorials. Hint: use `var`.

Comment: I used var but still the same issue.

Comment: Did you also declare `$div` and `$location` using `var` within the function? Please update your code in the question showing how you did so.